# Using .style imported into ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.1, symbology, style, style-manager

I have been handed a .style file by a coworker so that we consistently use similar color schemes. After downloading it, I went into Customize >>> Style manager >>> Styles... >>> Add style to list. There, I scrolled through to get my .style file and selected it. Now, a new folder appeared in my Style Manager with the styles that I imported. My ArcMap 10.1 Style Manager looks like this (red arrow shows the colors I want to access):

[image]

[image]

However, when I open a layer's properties and go to the symbology, I can only see the colour ramps available, but not the colors. Even if I change the symbology show from "graduated colours" to "features", the colors are not accesible, even though when I click on the "Symbol Selector" >>> "Style preferences" I see that the style is activated:

[image]

What I can do to access the colors of my .style on my symbol selector so that I can change my colors one by one to the desired one?

Comment: You can import style files from any location except the directory that is the default style subfolder of the UserDataPath setting in the Arcmap.exe.config file. (also check your co-worker is not on a higher version of arcgis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style folder named "colors" will add these to the color palette. The colors that I added were located here:

[image]